# How do active and passive transformations affect how a matrix is represented?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Following this question: [Active and passive transformations in Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844714/active-and-passive-transformations-in-linear-algebra)
I wanted to ask how do matrices change with each transformation and why is it so(proof or/and intuition).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an orthogonal transformation $T$ which brings a change in the coordinate system $S_0$ to a system $S_1$ 
And suppose a matrix $A$ transforms any vector $\mathbf r_0$ to $\mathbf r_0'$ in $S_0$ system

And I assume you are asking what would be the new matrix $A'$ in the system $S_1$

we can write $$\mathbf A \mathbf r_0=\mathbf r_0'$$
$$\mathbf Tr_0=\mathbf r_1$$
$$\mathbf T \mathbf r_0'=\mathbf r_1'$$
$$\mathbf A \mathbf T^{-1}\mathbf T \mathbf r_0=\mathbf r_0'$$
$$\mathbf T \mathbf A \mathbf T^{-1} \mathbf r_1=\mathbf r_1'$$

So the matrix $\mathbf A'=\mathbf T \mathbf A \mathbf T^{-1}$ in system $S_1$ is equivalent to the matrix $\mathbf A$ in $S_0$

The above is true for both active (axes fixed, vectors rotate) and passive (axes rotate, vectors fixr) transformations, the only change is that $\mathbf T$ is different in active and passive transformations

for example if the $\mathbf T$ represents active rotation in the anti-clockwise direction by an angle $\theta$ about the $z$ axis then
$$ T=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&0\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Fora  passive transformation replace $\theta$ by$-\theta$