# What do matrices do to the vectors?

Tags: vectors

Let’s consider the matrix shearing transformation. Does it change the space of the vector? So any further transformations that we do will add upon that. Or does it change the relation between vector in 2D space?

I know, it might sound as a stupid question, but I feel lost.

Comment: What is a 'matrix shearing transformation'?

Comment: The shear transformation. If we transform the square into parallelogram, for example.

Comment: How is it different from a matrix transformation?

Comment: You have one *matrix*, and many *matrices*.

Comment: I've edited my question. Thank you for pointing out my grammar mistake.

Comment: Both views are valid and it really depends on context. Look up “active” vs. “passive” transformations. [This question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1844714/265466) have a bare-bones explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to work with matrices and other coordinate-dependent constructs makes it difficult to learn the invariant (geometric) properties of vector spaces.

May I suggest starting by reading [the Linear Map article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) (it has a Russian version as well, if you prefer).  You will see that a linear transformation generally acts from a vector space to a vector space, and these two spaces may be either distinct or the same one.  For a deep, clean exposition, see P. Halmos's *Finite-dimensional vector spaces*.

For linear elastic deformations, the transformation acts from a space to itself.  For an explanation of how the physical model is set up, see A. Spencer's *Continuum mechanics*, or at least the chapter on elasticity in [Feynman's lectures on physics](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. Btw In Russian linear algebra is much more difficult to understand

Comment: Just to clarify: if , at first, I was in vector space where my 2 vectors were [1,0] and [0,1] respectively. Then I transform them with A(1) matrix: let's say I do 90 degree anticlockwise rotation. Now my basis vectors have changed, so for further transformation of A(1) I will take those new basis vectors that I received as an output from the rotation before?

Comment: Great question.  A transformation itself does not involve a basis.  The transformation simply tells to what vector in the range each vector in the domain must be mapped.

As for which basis to express either the original vector or the one resulting from applying the transformation, that is a completely separate decision.  I can have a transformation $A$ from a vector space $V$ to $V$, and two bases on $V$; say, $B = \{b_1, b_2, \ldots, \}$ and $B' = \{b'_1, b'_2, \ldots, \}$.  I can express a vector $x$ in coordinates w.r.t. basis $B$, while the vector $Ax$ in coordinates w.r.t. basis $B'$.

Comment: Or, I can write $Ax$ in terms of basis $B$.  Depends on what is the most convenient for the problem.


There is not necessarily a "new basis", or any basis--that's my point.  Every time you deal with a vector and need to write it out in coordinates, you decide which basis to use for that.

P. Halmos's book forces the student to separate these issues with unequaled clarity.  I recommend getting it it asap.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@avs, so my new linear map and vector space will look quite similar to this (with orange vectors as new basis ones)

[image]

Comment: Ok.  So, you have basis $B \; : \; b_1 = [1, 0], \; b_2 = [0, 1]$.  

Let's also introduce basis $B' \; : \; b'_1 = [1, 1], \; b'_2 = [1, -1]$.

How about we take your shear transformation $A$ and let it act on the basis vector $b_1$.  Express the resulting vector, $Ab_1$ in terms of the basis vectors $B$.  Now express $Ab_1$ in terms of the basis vectors $B'$.

The hardest part here is to keep track of which basis we are using.